# Regex negative lookahead not working as expected

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9. ]*(?!cs)
```

and the string

```
Hotfix H5.12.1.00.cs02_ADV_LCR
```

I want to match only untill

```
Hotfix H5.12.1.00
```

But the regex matches untill "cs02"

Shouldn't the negative lookahead have done the job?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/hQ2gD5/2

Comment: You may consider using a tempered greedy token if you need to use a negative lookahead: [`(?:(?!cs)[a-zA-Z0-9. ])*`](https://regex101.com/r/dS7cZ2/1). The real solution depends on whether you need `.cs` to be present in the string or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
(?:(?!\.cs)[a-zA-Z0-9. ])*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dS7cZ2/4).

This will work regardless of whether `.cs` is present in the string or not because the tempered greedy token matches any 0+ characters from the `[a-zA-Z0-9. ]` character class that is not `.cs`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use positive lookahead instead of negative lookahead.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9. ]*(?=\.cs)
```

or

```
[a-zA-Z0-9. ]+(?=\.cs)
```

Note that your regex `[a-zA-Z0-9. ]*(?!cs)` is greedy and matches all the characters until it reaches a boundary which isn't followed by `cs`. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/qB4qY4/1).

At first pattern `[a-zA-Z0-9. ]+` matches `Hotfix H5.12.1.00.cs02` greedily because this pattern greedily matches alphabets , dots and spaces. Once it see the underscore char, it stops matching where the two conditions is satisfied,

1. `_` won't get matched by `[a-zA-Z0-9. ]+`
2. `_` is not `cs`

It works same for the further two matches also.

Comment: thanks, this works but as I need the cs string to be present or not, the answer with negative lookahead provided by  Wiktor Stribiżew gets the job done

Comment: this https://regex101.com/r/dS7cZ2/3 ? Note that on php `g` is enabled by default. Don't know why you're willing to use negative lookahead instead of simple positive lookahead.